# Nonhomeomorphic CW-complexes that are stably homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Can one find two finite CW-complexes $X$ and $Y$ such that $X \times I$ is homeomorphic to $Y \times I$, where $I = [0, 1]$, but $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$?  I know how to find such topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, but not CW-complexes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

See example 1.4 in the paper "[Cancellation laws in topological products](http://www.morfismos.cinvestav.mx/Portals/0/SiteDocs/Articulos/Volumen2/No2/Zeron/santillan.pdf)" by E. Santillán, Morfismos, vol. 2, no. 2, 1998, pp. 67-74, and also the original example by R. H. Fox depicted on p.284 of his famous paper "[On a problem of S. Ulam concerning Cartesian products](http://eudml.org/doc/213133%E2%80%8E)", Fundamenta Mathematicae, vol. 34, no. 1, 1947, pp. 278-287. All these examples are finite CW complexes.